# Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse) In program ended

Tags: c++, class, pointers

Im doing a physics simulation and i have two classes, `Simulation` and `Renderer`.
I need to have them reference to each other and the problem is that when i pass
the reference to `Renderer` this happens.

Here is the code:

```
Renderer.cpp

Renderer::Renderer(Simulation* _sim) {
    sim = new Simulation(*_sim);
}

Renderer::~Renderer() {
    delete sim;
}

Renderer.hpp
class Renderer {
private:
    Simulation* sim;
public:
    Renderer(Simulation* _sim);
    ~Renderer();
};
```

EDIT:

Here is the requested code (the only thing i do with it is draw it):

```
Renderer.cpp
void Renderer::Draw() {

    for(auto obj : sim->objects) {
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        for(auto p : obj) {
            glColor3f(COLORS[p.id][0], COLORS[p.id][1], COLORS[p.id][2]);
            glVertex2f(p.x,p.y);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

The error is coming from `sim = new Simulation(*_sim);`, if i remove it,
no errors. No ideas of how to fix it?

Comment: No idea since you didn't show us what you're actually doing with the code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Which line produces the assertion fail?

Comment: The error is in line 52.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem myself. Double delete problem. Simulation already deleted itself when i was gonna delete it.
I've just removen `delete sim`.